# Unable to view gurobi variable attributes in visual studio for C# .net

Tags: .net, gurobi

The gurobi model runs, I can optimize, and debug, but in the debugger, the gurobi variables appear just as:     gvar    {Gurobi.GRBVar} Gurobi.GRBVar 
I cannot drill down and see any attributes, such as gvar.ub or gvar.X. Is there some way to do this?  (Using Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, gurobi 6.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Gurobi provides access to attributes and parameters via .NET properties since release 7.0 so this answer only applies to older releases.

---

The Gurobi .NET interface does not expose attributes as C# properties. You could simply create your own wrapper class to get this behavior. Here is an example wrapper for `GRBVar` variable objects:

```
using Gurobi;
using System;

public class Variable {

    private GRBVar _variable;

    public double LowerBound { get { return _variable.Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.LB); } }
    public double UpperBound { get { return _variable.Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.UB); } }

    public double ObjectiveCoefficient {
        get { return _variable.Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.Obj); }
        set { _variable.Set(GRB.DoubleAttr.Obj, value); }
    }

    public Variable(GRBVar variable) {
        if ((object)variable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("variable");
        _variable = variable;
    }
}
```

Now you can now inspect variable objects like this:

[image: Visual Studio Example]